# Confluent Kafka - Schema Registry on windows

Tags: confluent-platform

I happened to see an example how to run schema registry using "schema-registry-start.bat" from windows on 5.0.1

I didnt see the file in 5.5.0 . Is the schema registry not supported in windows now ?
IT seems only the way to go about running schema registry in windows through dockers . Please someone confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be using the community version of Confluent. In nutshell, Confluent provides support for Apache Kafka via these three distributions:

1. **Confluent Community**: Limited version of the distribution where only Apache Kafka components are provided (Kafka Brokers, Kafka Connect, Kafka Streams) and some technologies like Schema Registry, Connectors, ksqlDB, and REST Proxy that are based on the [Confluent Community License](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license/).
2. **Confluent Enterprise**: Unlimited version of the distribution that offers everything existing in the Confluent Community version, plus additional technologies like MQTT Proxy, C3, K8S Operator, Auto Data Balancer, Tiered Storage, RBAC, Secret Protection and Audit Logs, Schema Validation, Multi Region Clusters, and Replicator. It also offers some facilities such as proper support for Windows.
3. **Confluent Cloud**: Same as Confluent Enterprise but made available as a fully managed service in the cloud (AWS, Azure, and GCP supported) where you pay only for what you use and the infra is managed by Confluent SRE's.

The community version of Confluent **does not** offer the CLI to manage Schema Registry on Windows. Only the enterprise version does this. This does not even has to do with versions because even the 5.0.1 version of the community version does not offer support for Windows. So when you saw the scripts `schema-registry-start.bat` and `schema-registry-stop.bat` you were likely using the enterprise version.

Luckily, the enterprise version of Confluent is free forever for developers using up to one broker for testing purposes. Alternatively you can try [Confluent Cloud](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-cloud) for free where the first 3 months will have $200 of credit.

Comment: Thanks, It seems it is little different when it comes to linux version ? As the community version had the support for running schema registry. Nevertheless, enterprise seems little fat (1.1 GB ) compared with community(450MB), I will use linux version for now.

Comment: Yeah, the enterprise version has way more things. But if you're able to use the Linux version I'd encourage you. It runs smoothly!